# Python - how does the variable affect the loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am wondering why there is a different result when I change from arr[n] in version 1 to n in version 2:

**Version 1**

```
def summer_69(arr):
    list_sum2 = 0
    n = 0
    for arr[n] in range(arr[n] == 6, (arr[n]== 9) + 1):
            list_sum2 += arr[n]
    print(list_sum2)

summer_69([1, 3, 5])
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

**Result for Version 1**

```
0
0
```

**Version 2**

```
def summer_69(arr):
    list_sum2 = 0
    n = 0
    for n in range(arr[n] == 6, (arr[n]== 9) + 1):
            list_sum2 += arr[n]
    print(list_sum2)

summer_69([1, 3, 5])
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

**Result for Version 2**

```
1
4
```

Comment: We have a duplicate about `for a[i] in ...`, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 3):

that's not how range works.

in this line:

```
for n in range(arr[n] == 6, (arr[n]== 9) + 1):
```

`arr[n] == 6` and `(arr[n]== 9) + 1` are returning truth values because `==` is a comparison operator so `n` here at best takes values 0 or 1.

you want

```
for n in range(6, 10):
```

so that the value of `n` iterates from 6 to 9, `range()` being inclusive to the left and exclusive to the right